# Merging data frame generating extra coma

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following data frames

```
b = frozenset({'hi','how','are'})
c = frozenset({'we'})

d = frozenset({'hi','how'})
e = frozenset({'we','are'})

we = set()
we.add((b,c))

we2 =set()
we2.add((d,e))

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'we': [we,we],'value': [5,2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'we': [we2,we],'value': [6,12]})
```

df is :

```
               we             value
0   {((hi, how, are), (we))}    5
1   {((hi, how, are), (we))}    2
```

Here is df2:

```
               we             value
0   {((hi, how), (are, we))}    6
1   {((hi, how, are), (we))}    12
```

I left joined df and df2:

```
df.we = df.we.apply(tuple)
df2.we = df2.we.apply(tuple)
df3= pd.merge(df,df2,how='left',on='we')
```

The result is correct in terms of data but I have no idea where did the comas come from:

```
                  we        value_x value_y
0   (((hi, how, are), (we)),)   5   12
1   (((hi, how, are), (we)),)   2   12
```

How do I get:

```
                  we    value_x value_y
0   ((hi, how, are), (we))  5   12
1   ((hi, how, are), (we))  2   12
```

Comment: A tuple with 1 element is shown with an extra comma.

Comment: Thanks! I just read the basics. Looks like I need to trim the characters of the element manually.

Comment: It's not a character in the dataframe. It's just how `print()` shows tuples.

Comment: For instance, do `print(tuple([1]))` and it will print `(1,)`.

Comment: Alright! Thanks! I used df3.we =[i[0] for i in df3.we] and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to convert the set to a tuple but extract its only element.

```
df.we = df.we.apply(lambda x: next(iter(x)))
df2.we = df2.we.apply(lambda x: next(iter(x)))
df3= pd.merge(df,df2,how='left',on='we')
```

df3 is as expected

```
                       we  value_x  value_y
0  ((are, how, hi), (we))        5       12
1  ((are, how, hi), (we))        2       12
```

---

Alternatively, you could update your sets with the sequences instead of adding to them:

```
...
we = set()
we.update((b,c))

we2 =set()
we2.update((d,e))
```

For example `df` would be:

```
                       we  value
0  ((we), (are, how, hi))      5
1  ((we), (are, how, hi))      2
```

Now it makes sense to convert the set to a tuple and after:

```
df.we = df.we.apply(tuple)
df2.we = df2.we.apply(tuple)
df3= pd.merge(df,df2,how='left',on='we')
```

we also get for `df3`:

```
                       we  value_x  value_y
0  ((hi, are, how), (we))        5       12
1  ((hi, are, how), (we))        2       12
```